# Android 5+ Raster & Vector images conflict

Tags: android, raster, android-vectordrawable

I need to use a raster icons in API < 21, and a vector in 21+. In `drawable-***dpi` I put a raster icons. In `drawable-v21`, their vector counterparts with the same names.

For example, for **accounts.png**, I have my **accounts.xml** in `drawable-v21`. But when I run the application on API 21+, I see that vector icons are ignored. Raster icons from `drawable-***dpi` are used.

I cannot use Android Studio vector drawable compat by some reasons. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android always prefers the resources that are the most qualified for the device and `drawable-***dpi` is given a higher priority than `drawable-v21` as per the [table of resource qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#table2)

Therefore, you should place your vector icons in the `drawable-anydpi-v21` directory, which uses the `anydpi` qualifier to ensure that it takes priority.